# MySQL - Insert MD5 value into table 2 from calculation on table 1

Tags: mysql, md5

I've been working on this for some time now and I've been able to insert the MD5 calculated values from T2 to T1, but when I check the table, the same MD5 exists for many different combinations, which is incorrect.

I'm having trouble figuring out why this is not working as intended.

```
UPDATE t1 
INNER JOIN t2 on t1.sys_id=t2.chunk_id 
SET t1.md5sum =
(SELECT md5(GROUP_CONCAT(t2.data ORDER BY array)));
```

I know the calculated values work on t2 alone because I've tested this extensively without saving the value on this table.

SIDE NOTE: The reason I cannot save this value on t2 is because of the size. Even using PTOSC, it would take days to add a new column with a char(32) for just the MD5. Whereas t1 is a fraction of it's size.

Comment: md5 is not recommeded to use refer http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using this for anything of significance. This is not a md5 for a password.